# Помогите Доделать программу на Python

Tags: python-3.x

Я делаю прогноз погоды,но когда я запускаю программа не запускается Помогите плиз вот код

```
import pyowm

a = input("В каком городе вы проживаете")

owm = pyown.OWM('5a7f31bd4287b3d03838d8d373576dff', Language = "ru" 

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print( "В городе " + place + "сейчас" + w.get_detailed_status())
print( "Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp)

if temp < 10:
print( "Сейчас ппц как холодно")  
else if temp < 20:
print("Одевайся по теплее")
else if temp < 30
print("Теплынь!!!")
```

Comment: не хватает скобки в конце ``owm = pyown.OWM('5a7f31bd4287b3d03838d8d373576dff', Language = "ru" `` После этого будет еще несколько ошибок. Например, город записывается в ``a``, а используется ``place``, и еще разное.

Comment: Это абсолютно невалидный код. Это вообще, Python? :)

Comment: Ну и если "программа не запускается", то нужно читать сообщения об ошибках, а не бежать сразу за помощью.

Answer (score 2):

Как просили, надеюсь поможет...

***UPD:***

```py
import pyowm


town = input("В каком городе вы проживаете?: ")

owm = pyowm.OWM('5a7f31bd4287b3d03838d8d373576dff', language="ru")

observation = owm.weather_at_place(town)
weather = observation.get_weather()
temperature = weather.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
detailed_status = weather.get_detailed_status()

print(
    "В городе %s сейчас %s\n" % (town, detailed_status) +
    "Температура в районе %s°C" % temperature
)

if temperature < 10:
    print("Сейчас ппц как холодно")
elif temperature < 20:
    print("Одевайся по теплее")
elif temperature > 30:
    print("Теплынь!!!")
```

Comment: я бы еще добавил ``else: print("Ппц как жарко")`` :)

Comment: @Эникейщик У него условия ещё сбились, я обновил, вроде теперь как задумывалось, дополнит сам, надеюсь :)

Comment: if < 20 else if < 10 - фигня.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Порядок сравнений я имею в виду. Всё что <10, то пройдёт по первой ветке с <20, а значит код второй ветки никогда не выполняется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Точно, Вы полностью правы, упустил из виду. Спасибо, за хорошее замечание, уже исправил.

Comment: Ага, я ещё выводимые строки местами поменял. Но от 20 до 30 ничего не выводится.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, предлагали добавить else, но пусть это сделает автор на своё усмотрение, всё-таки ему нужна была помощь не в этом.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: @BotKotik Рад, что Вам это помогло. В таком случае, пометьте, пожалуйста, ответ, как правильный.